# Efficient way to get CIO-1?

Tags: httprequest, microsoft-graph-api

I was assigned a task where I receive a bunch of employees and I need to get their CIO-1 (means their boss's boss's boss... all the way to the boss whose manager is the CIO). But I don't know if I'm doing it in an efficient way. This is my algorithm:

For every given employee, perform an api request to microsoft graph to get their manager. Then perform another api request to get that manager's manager... and do this until I get the one whose manager is our CIO. This means if I was given 500 employees, I would be performing an HTTP request inside a `for` loop, and perform another `for` loop inside to go up the "manager chain."

Is this ok? Would Microsoft Graph cut me off because I would be performing many many queries in a short amount of time?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an algorithm question than a graph question really. But yes you do need to query the data at the end of the day.
However there are smarter ways than others.
Rather than building a loop that queries all your initial employee's boss and within that have another loop to get the higher level boss and so on... You could do it a different way.
First make sure you leverage [batch queries](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/30daysmsgraph-day-14-batch-processing/) to minimize the number of round-trips.
Second, I think it's safe to assume that at some point, some sets of employees are going to have the same boss. And rather than querying multiple times who's that boss' boss, you need to make sure you only do it once.
There are a couple of different ways of doing that, maintaining a tree, an index, always applying distinct on data sets...
Lastly, keep in mind that a loop in a loop algorithmic complexity is o(n)^2. Which is always worse than having two subsequent loops (one after another). So trying to flatten your algorithm will help, and it will also help you build batches.

On the throttling part, make sure you go though the [guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling). Yes you might experience that, however there are a couple of ways to optimize.